# What is meant by "this when"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I read this sentence in [The Hindu](https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/lead/high-science-with-low-development/article24747194.ece):

> We have not seen national will on a similar scale since. **This when** we urgently need an agricultural initiative comparable in its transformative capacity today.

What does "this when" mean? And what does the whole sentence imply?

Comment: Please give the name of that newspaper you read?

Comment: Considering the typo in 'comparable', 'is' could be lost from 'This is when' as well.

Comment: The Hindu of August 22.

Comment: Actually it was me who misspelt comparable.

Comment: Not any single dictionary describes such usage of **this when**. However you can consider reading this sentence: **"do this, when the lights go out."**
There is comma between this and when in the sentence. Link: https://weather.com/storms/severe/video/do-this-when-the-lights-go-out

Comment: @VishalGhulati I found a [link](https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/lead/high-science-with-low-development/article24747194.ece) to the article and read the sentence in context. _This when_ refers to the Green Revolution from the previous paragraph. and links to the sentence  _"We have not seen national will on a similar scale since._ The author is saying that India needs another  "Green Revolution".Unfortunately the editor of the article should have picked _"this"_ up as a _dangling modifier_ (do a google search) as the meaning of the original sentence is indeed unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence is correct but it's unusual to see this phrasing in a newspaper.  You can interpret "This when..." as meaning "This *thing that I have just mentioned is occurring* when..."  It emphasizes that the thing is occurring *even though* the next thing is true.

For example,

> [Soundings taken by the British gunboats in their ascent in 1900 gave 63 1/2 fathoms of water in two places, and this when the water at Ichang was rather less than 6 feet above zero mark!](https://books.google.com/books?id=-_L-nD1893cC&lpg=PA6&dq=%22and%20this%20when%20%22&pg=PA6#v=onepage&q=%22and%20this%20when%20%22&f=false)

means "...and *the soundings taken by the British gunboats did this* when..."

Or

> [...when taking a journey, he arms himself, and seeks to go well accompanied; when going to sleep, he locks his doors; when even in his house he locks his chests; and this when he knows there be laws and public officers...](https://books.google.com/books?id=7Sc4p5-ghJcC&pg=PA77&lpg=PA77&dq=%22and%20this%20when%20he%20knows%20there%20be%20laws%22&source=bl&ots=9wBpGqMy9u&sig=1mv-383OMGIDWeZKQv1tv1WuZiw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjxnIqS8oXdAhXHm-AKHUYzCt8Q6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22and%20this%20when%20he%20knows%20there%20be%20laws%22&f=false)

means "...and *he does all these things* when he knows (etc.)"

So in the newspaper article, the two sentences

> We have not seen national will on a similar scale since.  This when we urgently need an agricultural initiative comparable in its transformative capacity today.

can be interpreted as

> We have not seen national will on a similar scale since, **and this is a fact even though** we urgently need an agricultural initiative comparable in its transformative capacity today